Winsock sockets requests per second processing?
I'm trying to find out how many requests per second to allow to our old Winsock 2.2 server. Currently, it's on a dev server with an i5 4 core CPU. I have it set up to run 2 threads per processor so 8 threads. The server "listen" socket is on the main thread and 8 spawned threads to handle TCP requests.
Our payload is small at roughly 64 bytes (not including any TCP wrapper). We send that 64 bytes every 250 milliseconds and the server seems to handle it just fine. If we have 8 clients (say 1 per thread) is this frequency ok, or can it handle a lot more, or is this frequency too much? I'm looking for an answer that could hopefully show how it would scale if we ran the Winsock server on a 4 core, 8 core, 16 core, to 32 core CPU.
64 x 4 x 60 = 15360 bytes per minute per client or roughly 0.9 Mb per hour if my math is correct. So bandwidth is not really an issue. Average processing time on the client is under 50 milliseconds so I'm hoping we could raise the frequency to every 50 milliseconds without affecting server performance. I could just set it to every 50 milliseconds and see what happens but I don't know if that's the best approach.
TIA

Depends on how much per-client processing is requires to produce that 64 byte chunk every half second, and how much network bandwidth you have available and want to consume.

If you really want to know, you should set up a test and measure it.  I expect you could handle thousands of requests per second, but you should try it.

Tim I was thinking that but if it's in the thousands and we are nowhere near the limits then I won't bother.

Chris the 64 bytes is already in memory and only changes every few minutes but we have to send it to keep everything in sync. If its the same we only send a 4 byte ping but 64 bytes every 250 milliseconds is worst case scenario.
